# Android 13 playbackstate callback not called ( from notification buttons)

Tags: android, notifications, android-mediaplayer, mediaplayback

For mediaplayer, `ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT` and  `ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS` both are working fine from notification buttons for android 12 and below.
it seems that android 13 has a different behavior according to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13).

to be clear, below buttons in the pictures are not working in android 13 only.
[image]

Android developer mentioned that playbackstate should be used for android 13

> "For apps targeting Android 13 (API level 33) and higher, the system
> derives media controls from PlaybackState actions."

the problem is that in android 13 playstechange is never called, even `public int onStartCommand` is never called.

tried below code but even no use

```
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "MediaSession", receiver, null);
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, 0, 0)
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
            .build());

    mediaSession.setActive(true);

 mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        // Implement callbacks

        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            final String intentAction = mediaButtonEvent.getAction();

            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
                final KeyEvent event = mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (event == null) {
                    return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
                }
                final int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
                final int action = event.getAction();
                if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keycode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                if (isPlaying()) {
                                    playbackAction(1);                                        
                                    pauseMedia();                                        
                                    updateMetaData();
                                } else { // want to continue playing
                                    playbackAction(0);
                                    playMedia();
                                }
                            }                              
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                            pauseMedia();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:

                            process_play_request();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                            skipToPrevious();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                            skipToNext();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
        }});
```

and tried to add this code, but also no use:

```
         MediaControllerCompat mController;

    mController = new MediaControllerCompat(this, mediaSession.getSessionToken());


    mController.registerCallback(mCallback);
    mCallback.onPlaybackStateChanged(mController.getPlaybackState());
    mCallback.onMetadataChanged(mController.getMetadata());

private final MediaControllerCompat.Callback mCallback = new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat playbackState) {
        onUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMetadataChanged(MediaMetadataCompat metadata) {
        onUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionDestroyed() {
    }

    private void onUpdate() {
    }
};
```

This issue has no relation to `android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS`    as runtime permission is requested and granted but still no use.

Noting that after media player perpared, SetState is called as below:

```
mediaPlayer.start();

            setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);

private void setState(int state) {
    long position = 0;

    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder builder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
    builder.setState(state, position, 1.0f);
    builder.setActions(
            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT);
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(builder.build());


}
```

suggestions please

Comment: Your `PlaybackState` says you only support the `PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE` and not skip to next or skip to previous. Why would you expect actions that you specifically said you don't support?

Comment: Tested ".setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)" but no use, I edited my question

Comment: That's not how you declare support for multiple actions - each call to `setActions` replaces the previous set. You'd need to `or` them together in one call.

Comment: | is already included in SetState(int).

Comment: Noting that every thing is working fine in android 12 and lower versions. problem is only in android 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add a few override methods to your `MediaSessionCompat.Callback()`:

```
mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    // Implement callbacks
    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
        // your implements
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        super.onPlay();
        // your play() implements
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // your pause() implements
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
        super.onSkipToNext();
        // your next() implements
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
        super.onSkipToPrevious();
        // your prev() implements
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
        // your seek() implements
    }
});
```

You will receive the action buttons event in these callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and then I realized I was doing one thing wrong I had to set those actions when I was building my notification along with action_seek_to first set the state to playing or paused and then set action using (or) that's it hope it will help

Comment: I don't get your answer, again every thing is working fine in android 12. problem is only in android 13.

Comment: Well i am sorry for that here is my repository https://github.com/AbhinavSachan/Atomyk_Play/blob/thrid_branch/AtomykPlay/app/src/main/java/com/atomykcoder/atomykplay/services/MediaPlayerService.kt. Go to the method where i am initiating media session and then watch buildNotification function watch it carefully all the stuff for your solution is there